# Getting ServerNotFoundError when using gevent/greenlets with requests

Tags: python, gevent, httplib2, greenlets

I'm trying to paralellize the retrieval of data from a remote API. The remote API doesn't have any bulk capability, so for each object I need, I have to make a separate GET request.

I've added gevent into the mix. It works great sometimes, but if I try the same set of requests again, 50 of 100 will fail with this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/Users/---/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1570, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/Users/---/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1317, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/Users/---/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1258, in _conn_request
    raise ServerNotFoundError("Unable to find the server at %s" % conn.host)
ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at my.remote.host

<Greenlet at 0x10c6eacd0: function_name(<Object1>, <Object2>, u'zebra', True)> failed with ServerNotFoundError
```

Any thoughts on ways to resolve this? Is this a result of too many requests too quickly? If so, is there an easy way to throttle the number of greenlets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gevent has been known to cause some DNS issues with python-requests (which you inadvertently and incorrectly tagged) as part of this question. Luckily for you, we have seen this issue before and the user [resolved it](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1202#issuecomment-13881265) like so

```
gevent.dns.resolve_ipv4('example.com')
# However you make your httplib2 call.
```

With that in mind, another user noted that this [may already be fixed in a new version of gevent](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1202#issuecomment-26219026).

Regardless if the above snippet works for you, you should probably try upgrading gevent to make sure it isn't that.